ESTA for dual national: what can happen if I lie about being American?
Please let me know what could happen... I was born in the US as an American - am now naturalized French, and have residency in the Dominican Republic (where all my documents say I'm French).
I didn't renew my American passport when it expired (and very don't want another one).
I already traveled to the States on an ESTA about 10 years ago and had no issues, but they didn't ask me if I had dual nationality. AND my flight leaves in 2 days.
I was planning on just pretending to be French again, but this question about dual nationality kind of threw me, especially since my birthplace is US.
What can happen if I lie and hide my US nationality?

Last time I went to the states was about 10 years and I simply forgot to take my US passport when I went to the airport, so they sent me to get an etsa, that I bought like in the news-stand kind of place at the airport and they hardly asked me anything... so I didn't have to "lie"
Yes, probably my bad that I didn't check to see if things got more complicated.
I did actually do something stupid on that trip and told the immigration officer I was also American. He told me that was suspicious and sent me to another line where I had to go through another metal detector (and they took away my ham sandwich) but that was the extent of it.
Thank you all for you input.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Have you been paying taxes to the US government, or at least filing tax returns?

Remember about fingerprints. 10 years ago you gave them, now it depends. It is risky. Not telling the truth to authorities can be very bad.

As a US citizen you are required to enter the US with a US passport. If you want to travel to the US you need to get a US passport whether you like one or not.
You can apply for an ESTA as a dual citizen with US citizenship. Sometimes, it's granted, sometimes it's not. There doesn't seem to be any particular rhyme or reason behind the decision.

What can happen if I lie and hide my US nationality?

Unknown. If you are lucky, no one will find out. If they do find out, it's hard to tell what will happen. Obviously your ESTA will be denied. Lying on an ESTA is criminal offense, but if the CBP will take any further legal action is anyone's guess. As a US citizen you cannot be denied entry in the United States, but an airline can certainly deny you boarding without a valid US passport.

The airline is not going to deny boarding to a passenger presenting a valid French passport with valid ESTA.  However, the ESTA is validated by sending an electronic message to the US government, which responds with a message saying whether to board the passenger or not.  It looks like the logic behind that system isn't so intricate as to identify the passenger as a US citizen and indicate "DO NOT BOARD" for that reason, but because there is no statutory or regulatory law covering this situation, the system's logic could change at any time.  In other words, "unknown" is right.

@phoog The airline denying boarding was following on from the answer's premise that the ESTA has already been denied. No ESTA + no US passport = denied.

You broke the law last time by entering as a French citizen, because US citizens must enter the US as a US citizen. Since your flight is in 2 days, how on Earth have you not sorted the ESTA already? In any case, get it done NOW, answer "no" to the question about dual citizenship and pray that it gets approved. To make the process smoother, at the border you should present your expired US passport if you still have it.

I didn't renew my American passport when it expired (and very don't want another one)

If you ever intend to visit the US in the future, you'll have to renew your US passport in advance of it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
